# Realm does not return exception on React native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, realm

I'm using Realm Database on React native. In my Model Schema id field is required. When id field is undefined Realm does return an exception and adding data is not done. Why Realm does not return an exception in try catch??

Model Schema:

```
export default class ServicesModule {
    cache = {};
}

ServicesModule.schema = {
    name: "ServicesModule",
    primaryKey: "id",
    properties: {
        id: "int",
        title: "string?"
    }
};
```

Insert data:

```
try {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         realm().write(() => {
            resolve(realm().create("ServicesModule", {title: 'Test exception'}, true));
         });
      });
} catch(e) {
   console.error(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your promise does not reject. Try with:

```
try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     try{

        realm().write(() => {
           resolve(realm().create("ServicesModule", {title: 'Test exception'}, true));
        });

    }catch(error){
        reject(error);
    }
  });
} catch(e) {
 console.error(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Outer `try catch` block is unnecessary since returning a `Promise` will never fail.